# Bash not reading file to variable

Tags: linux, bash

I have a simple bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
TEXT=$(<"$(pwd)/data/test.json")
echo "$TEXT"
```

Which should read the whole file and assign it to a variable `TEXT` however, when I run it, the only output I get is a newline character. In the same directory, as the script is, I tried to run

```
cat "$(pwd)/data/test.json"
```

And it gives me the following output

```
{ "data": true }
```

Why is the bash script not working?

Edit:

My bash version is `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What is the output if you change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash -x`

Comment: @anubhava If you meant while running in the terminal, it outputs `{ "data": true }`

Comment: @FredrikPihl the output is still just a newline character

Comment: what is output of `file test.json`? I'm thinking dos-lineendings...

Comment: @FredrikPihl `data/test.json: ASCII text, with no line terminators`

Comment: Cannot reproduce with input as `$ echo -n '{ "data: true }' > test.json`.

Comment: @august: Add your bash version to your question.

Comment: FWIW, prepending `$(pwd)` isn't necessary. `"data/test.json"` would work just as well. Relative paths are resolved relative to the current directory.

Comment: And `$(pwd)` in particular is really slow and expensive (it forks off a whole new shell, just to have that shell run `pwd`, and then read its output over a FIFO). `"$PWD"` is a much, *much* more efficient way to get the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you executing your script? Are you typing `sh script.sh`? Make sure you do `./script.sh` so it executes with `/bin/bash` not `/bin/sh`.

Answer (score 0):

To read a file in a variable, you can simply use the `cat` command.

```
TEXT="$(cat $(pwd)/data/test.json)"
```

The double quotes ensure the newlines are kept

```
echo "$TEXT"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That does work, however, according to [this](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/cmdsubst#specialities) I should also be able to use `$( <FILE )`

Answer (score 0):

use "bash {scriptname}" or "./{scriptname}"

also, you don't have to cat or echo to get the var set:
VAR=$(